# Diagrams in Phabricator

Tags: phabricator

Does Phabricator allow integration with tools like Gliffy or Lucidchart for making diagrams in wiki?

How can we use Phabricator as wiki to do architecture diagrams, are there any examples?

Answer (score 1):

Phabricator currently supports only Graphviz, see https://secure.phabricator.com/T3964 and http://www.graphviz.org/. Feel free to file requests for additional implementations.

Comment: As of the end of 2015 support for dot (Graphviz) was removed from Phabricator.  For details of why see ticket [T9408](https://secure.phabricator.com/T9408).  I think there are some notes on how people can roll their own own solution.  There is also a way to enable support, if you are happy to accept the security vulnerability it brings.  (I was just looking for answers to the same question and took a while to find the now non-working syntax followed by the ticket that explains why support was pulled)